# Problem in displaying data from database in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

i have a problem when i run a page.jsp :

```
Exception while calling encodeEnd on component : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /compteListe.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable,Id: j_id_jsp_1879226420_1][Class: javax.faces.component.UIColumn,Id: j_id_jsp_1879226420_2][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText,Id: j_id_jsp_1879226420_4]}
```

Caused by:

```
org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException - /compteListe.jsp(29,13) '#{l.Identifiant}' Property 'Identifiant' not found on type com.bankonet.bean.Compte
```

but when i do `System.out.println (rs.getString (1));`..., it works well and displays data !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the property name itself actually starts with 2 uppercased characters, the property name in EL needs to start with lowercase, so:

```
#{l.identifiant}
```

This requires a `public` no-arg getter method with name `getIdentifiant()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException - /compteListe.jsp(29,13) '#{l.Identifiant}' Property 'Identifiant' not found on type com.bankonet.bean.Compte
```

It searches for a Field with name `Identifiant` in class `com.bankonet.bean.Compte` with standard setter/getter methods , which it doesn't find and so the error

> but when i do System.out.println (rs.getString (1));..., it works well and displays data !!

It doesn't relate to your problem. You need to pass a collection to view to produce view